# RegExp with finer results

Tags: c#, regex

```
string STR = "The Quick Brown Fox Jumps";
string PTR = "[A-Z][a-z]+ [A-Z][a-z]+";
MatchCollection MCZ = Regex.Matches( STR, PTR ) ;   
if ( MCZ.Count > 0 )        
{
    string RTN ="";
    foreach ( Match x in MCZ )
    RTN += x.Value + "\n" ;
    MessageBox.Show( RTN );
}
else
    MessageBox.Show("Noop");
```

Hi...
My result goes like this;

```
The Quick
Brown Fox
```

But, I'd like to have;

```
The Quick
Quick Brown
Brown Fox
Fox Jumps
```

Nice tips, Please !!

Regards.

Comment: There are several better ways of doing this without using regular expressions...

Comment: @joaumg Thanks comment. Above codes are short version, my RegExp is somewhat long and a bit complex. For me, RegExp is an important condition.

Comment: I've tried to find out "starting position option/first matching position return option", but have failed. They are all "just running" blindly.

Comment: Why is regex important to you for this problem?

Comment: @ClickRick Never mind, it is a little taste of mine. You can do it with your own ways of working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:
    `(?<=(?<v>\w+)\s+)(?<v>\w+)`

I can't link the direct result to regexstorm.net (because there are parenthesis that will not work?!?!?) but try it on [`http://regexstorm.net/tester`](http://regexstorm.net/tester)

Please see the table. Each match contains two captures for group v.

[SAMPLE](http://ideone.com/lszvAX):

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var input = "The Quick Brown Fox Jumps";

        var regex = new Regex(@"(?<=(?<v>\w+)\s+)(?<v>\w+)");
        foreach (var match in regex.Matches(input).Cast<Match>())
        {
            var value = string.Join(" ", match.Groups["v"].Captures.Cast<Capture>().Select(x => x.Value));

            Console.WriteLine(value);
        }
    }
}
```

The output will be as expected.

Comment: Looks good, real good. 
Works good, real Good. 
ThanKSSSS !! I'm loving it.

Answer (score 0):

As I said, there are better ways of doing it...

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string str = "The Quick Brown Fox Jumps";

        string result = "";

        var tokens = str.Split(' ');

        for(int i = 0; i < tokens.Length - 1; i += 1) {
            result += tokens[i] + ' ' + tokens[i + 1] + "\n";
        }

        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks millions. That is not an answer though, is a really good starting point. I could run RegExp upon your nice result. Regards.